# Gobble gobble - Are the two meanings related?

Tags: etymology

Turkeys say, "gobble". We also "gobble" down a lot of turkey on Thanksgiving. This is just a bit of idle musing, but are the two meanings of this word somehow related via the American & Canadian holidays?

Comment: I was just watching a program about wild turkeys, and apparently they make all sorts of noises - upwards of 20 different sounds - but not a single one could be accurately described as sounding like "gobble gobble".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Etymonline has [this](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=gobble&searchmode=none):

> **gobble (1)** 
>   "eat fast," c.1600, probably partly echoic, partly frequentative of *gob*, via *gobben* "drink something greedily." Related: *Gobbled*; *gobbling*.
>
> **gobble (2)** 
>   "turkey noise," 1680, probably imitative.

The Free Dictionary [agrees](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gobble). So it appears that these are actually two unrelated words that just happen to be spelled identically (much like *cleave*).

Answer (score 0):

The *O.E.D.* lists "gobble" as a noun meaning *mouth*, and "gobbling" as *gorging*, the latter dating from 1630. Still, I would not be surprised if the verb form meaning the sound a turkey makes is at least in some sense onomatopoeic.  Where the two senses may be related is likely to be a confusion of the two.

Comment: Onomatopoea is my favorite word.